# Como atualizar multiplas linhas no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela (`respostas`) MYSQL assim:

```
ID|resposta
1 | A
2 | B
3 | B
4 | C
```

Aí ao enviar o formulario abaixo ele deve atualizar a coluna resposta de acordo com o valor de cada input:

```
<form method="post">
 <input name="1">
 <input name="2">
 <input name="3">
 <input name="4">
</form>
```

Aí não sei como montar a query para ataulizar as tabelas. O que pensei é fazer varios updates, mas acredito que deva existir uma forma mais simples.

Na forma abaixo, seria gerado na verdade por um foreach:

```
UPDATE repostas SET resposta = "$_POST['1']" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE repostas SET resposta = "$_POST['2']" WHERE id = 2
UPDATE repostas SET resposta = "$_POST['3']" WHERE id = 3
UPDATE repostas SET resposta = "$_POST['4']" WHERE id = 4
```

Comment: voce já criou o `foreach` ou somente citou ele na pergunta como exemplo ?